# Flow using directory "flow-typed" even though I've configured another [lib] value in .flowconfig

Tags: javascript, flowtype

My `.flowconfig` file specifies an alternative lib directory named `decls`:

```
$ cat .flowconfig  | grep -A1 libs
[libs]
    decls/
```

… and I have verified that declarations are indeed picked up from there.

Yet, the presence of a `flow-typed` directory created with [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed) causes Flow to pick up its definitions from the `flow-typed` directory instead.

I am using `flow-bin` version `0.27.0`.

Reading the main Flow documentation I found no reference to any special handling with respect to the `flow-typed` directory. The only reference to its special status is given in the the [third party documentation page for flow-typed](https://flowtype.org/docs/third-party.html) where the wording clearly states that a different directory can be used by changing the `lib` configuration in `.flowconfig`:

> If you need to customize the directory where libdefs are stored in
>   your project, you can do so by adding a [libs] configuration to your
>   .flowconfig file:

Is the behaviour I am observing a bug or is it a feature that Flow will always use directory `flow-typed` (if it exists) regardless of the `[lib]` setting in `.flowconfig` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's worth noting that Flow v0.27 is pretty old. I recommend upgrading.

[This function](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/f446f9e6698c08da9693840399b0b5df4d1c15e8/src/commands/serverCommands.ml#L126) contains the special handling for flow-typed. Library locations specified under `libs` are used *in addition* to the `flow-typed` folder, not instead of it. It sounds like you're describing intended behavior.

Why do you want to force Flow to ignore the `flow-typed` folder? Why bother having the `flow-typed` folder at all if you want to ignore it?

Comment: The situation is that `flow-typed` brings me a number of useful libdefs however there is a particular package (chai) were some features I am using are not covered, so I was hoping to be able to *override* the definitions fetched by `flow-typed` for one particular package with my own (while keeping the others). Experimenting with various configurations I stumbled on this thing. I didn't provide the context to keep it simple. I am trying to keep the libdefs fetched by `flow-typed` out of version control (even though this is not the advised approach).

Comment: I see. It seems reasonable to change the precedence so that user-defined libdef locations are preferred over the flow-typed folder. I'll see if folks are receptive to changing that.

Barring that, your options are to contribute the changes you need to `flow-typed` or to explicitly list the packages that you want `flow-typed` to install in some sort of build script, rather than just running `flow-typed install` and letting it fetch all of them.

Comment: Note: The library locations are specified under `libs` not `lib`